# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'execCommand' of undefined at execCmd at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not able to convert selected text in text area to bold on clicking bold button.Please help.This is my code. It shows the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'execCommand' of undefined  at execCmd at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>Editor</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
  .navbar {
      font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      background-color:     #A9A9A9;

      border: 0;
      font-size: 9px !important;
      letter-spacing: 4px;
      opacity: 0.9;
  }

  /* text color*/
  .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand { 
      color: black!important;
     font-weight: bold;
  }

  .nav-pills>li>a:hover {
    background-color: #6495ED;
}
  .nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}

 #body { padding-top: 90px; }

  #myText{

width: 95%;
height: 700px;
}

#editor{
text-align:center;
}

  </style>

</head>
<body id="body" >


<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" >

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills " id="pill1">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>

            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onclick="execCmd()" ><i class="fa fa-bold" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button></li>
            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-italic" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></li>
            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-underline" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button></li>
            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-strikethrough" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></li>
             </ul>

</div></div></div>
</nav>

<div id="editor">
        <textarea id="myText" name="myText" placeholder="Start typing here...."></textarea>
    </div>

<script>

function execCmd(command)
    {
    myText.document.execcommand(command, false,null);
    }

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why would a textarea have a document?Next it is execCommand, case matters. Thirdly, you are not passing a command to the function. Forth, you need to be using contentEditable, not a textarea.

Comment: I've switched to iframe. This code works.
[link]https://jsfiddle.net/anchal_g/mpuz7v30/
@ epascarello 48

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/anchal_g/mpuz7v30/5/